# Distributing a Leads list on a scheduled basis

Tags: leads, scheduled-job

I have a giant list of potential clients which I want to import into Leads. But I don't want to distribute all of them at one time. I would like to distribute a subset amount to the sales team every week. (let's say 50 a week)

I was thinking of maybe importing all of them at once into a custom object - and then somehow using a scheduled job to kick off every week to create the Leads from the entries. My problem is that I can't figure out how to only pull 50 every week.

Anybody got any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take this approach:

1. Create a boolean field called `Distributed` in Lead object. (Or, you can consider from Lead Status itself)
2. Create a schedule job which will run weekly and pull up those leads which are not distributed.

   > SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Distributed__c = false LIMIT 50
3. Take this list and update `OwnerId` to a `queue` and `Distributed__c = true`
4. Also, you may think of creating scheduled report to send to those queue members taking these last 50 lead records.

**Code example:**

```
global class WeeklyLeadProcessor implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute (SchedulableContext scx)
    {

        Group group = [Select Id, Name FROM Group 
                       WHERE Type = 'Queue' 
                       AND Name = 'Distributed_Queue']

        List<Lead> lstLead = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId 
                              FROM Lead 
                              WHERE Distributed__c = false LIMIT 50];
        for(Lead leadObj:lstLead)
        {
            leadObj.Distributed__c = true;
            leadObj.OwnerId = group.Id;
        }
        update lstLead;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Santanu. That seems like the perfect solution. Can you show me some more of the code which is necessary here ?